# Error When Installing DBI Perl Module

Tags: perl, dbi, fedora20

Here is my output, any suggestions? I've tried installing by  perl -MCPAN -e shell and then force install DBI.

```
cpan[10]> force install DBI
Running install for module 'DBI'
Running make for T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.636-sGWX9V

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz

gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"1.636\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.636\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"  -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter Perl.c
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [Perl.o] Error 127
  TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  /bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz                        : make NO
```

Comment: Using fedora 20, can you recommend me a C compiler and installation procedure? I verified that "make" is installed.

Comment: Erm, [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/)?

Comment: You should almost never use the force option. All it does is skip failing tests, which means that even if the installation succeeds, it's probably broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message:

```
    /bin/sh: gcc: command not found
```

so you need to install gcc

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you have already seen, installing `gcc` will fix the problem.

But I wonder why you don't use the pre-packaged version.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-DBI
```

Also, do you realise that Fedora 20 is now unsupported? I strongly suggest that you upgrade to a supported version (Fedora 24 or 25).